# How to set more than one cookie in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is how I set one cookie, but how to set two or more?

```
var head = {};
head['Set-Cookie'] = name+'='+value
res.writeHead(200, head);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`setHeader` example](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) in the docs, you can specify an array of values. Since [this commit](https://github.com/sstephenson/node/commit/f10a41b127197ec58f82180ed292725a1173fad4) it should work for `writeHead` as well.